# Regarding Export list to excel

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

One of my SP list has items over 55,000 when I try to export to excel it is retrieving only 52,000 records. Exactly which resource throttling settings we need to modify to retrieve 52,000 plus list items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually From SharePoint 2010 export to excel limit was followed and here the link to that explanation from TechNet. Also note that this setting is not configurable.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813(v=office.14).aspx

[image: Screenshot from the above link]

Answer (score 2):

You did not write which SP version nor which Excel version. I fould this solution that might help

> It turns out the query threshold is observed from Office 2010 (not sure about the 52k rows vs default 5000 rows in a view). If you increase the threshold in CA - web application's general settings/resource throttling, you will be able to export the whole list (of the max set in list view threshold (if above 52k). Make sure you re-set it back when done.

[source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe3f0dac-700e-4ea4-b1bf-1774542f0b19/sp2010-export-to-excel-2010-only-52000-rows-with-excel-2007-all-rows-why?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)